# Unable to Connect to Postgresql using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to the Postgresql database using Eclipse. I added a new Connection profile and entered the following below:

[image]

I am able to successfully Test the connection.
[image]

But when I try to connect, the database isn't displayed. How should I fix this?
[image]

Comment: is your database name postgres ? I think postgres is the default database that postgreSQL has.

Comment: yes my database name is postgres

Comment: Which version precisely are you using? Please update the question title or add this information to the question text.